"InvalidCheckoutSessionStatus" Error while firing CompleteCheckoutSession GraphQL End-Point
I am working with Amazon Pay and Adobe Commerce integration. I have Amazon Version 5.14.1. I have integrated this in Headless architecture using GraphQL.
I am able to redirect to Amazon page to enter login details and select the shipping and payment details. After that, I am getting redirected to Checkout page on the Magento with Prefilled Shipping address and Payment method as Amazon selected.
However When I hit the Place order button we are calling "completeCheckoutSession" GraphQL is called and this is where the error happens.
here is the Error that we are getting,
{
"reasonCode": "InvalidCheckoutSessionStatus",
"message": "You tried to call an operation on a Checkout Session that is in a state where that operation is not allowed",
"status": 422
}
completeCheckoutSession is defined in this class "Amazon\Pay\Model\CheckoutSessionManagement".
can anybody help me with the resolution of the issue?
I have tried adding the logs and it is giving 422 HTTP status code and hence cancelling the order and throwing an error as per the code.

From the order review page, the Place Order button should actually be invoking a request to UpdateCheckoutSession, then redirecting the customer to the amazonPayRedirectUrl before you'll be able to make the request to CompleteCheckoutSession.

Thanks Debbie for the help. Yes, it worked.
